# Gesture Recognition - Manipulation Events do not fire

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-10, scrollviewer

I am trying to implement gesture recognition using ManipulationStarted and ManipulationDelta events in Windows 10 mobile(UW) app. But there is one problem - they do not fire.

Most likely the problem is my overcomplicated xaml view (I have HorizontalyScrollable GridView inside ListView - and to enable vertical scroll it's all packed in ScrollViewer). But I tried adding those events to all containers and they still did not fire.

Does anyone have/know any sollution ? Below is my xaml page tree:

```
     <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" x:Name="SubscribersView" ManipulationStarted="SubscribersView_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationDelta="SubscribersView_ManipulationDelta">
      (......)   
                    <ListView 
                          Margin="0"
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          SelectionMode="None"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" 
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >

                     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                (......)
                                <GridView Grid.Row="1" 
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                      Margin="-10"
                                      SelectionMode="None"
                                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" 
                                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" 
                                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

                                    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></VirtualizingStackPanel>
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                </GridView>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution - I used ViewChanged of scrollviwer : below is solution

```
private void SubscribersView_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                var sv = sender as ScrollViewer;

                var verticalOffset = sv.VerticalOffset;
                var minVerticalOffset = sv.ExtentHeight - sv.ViewportHeight;
                var maxVerticalOffset = sv.ScrollableHeight;

                if (maxVerticalOffset < 0 || verticalOffset == maxVerticalOffset || minVerticalOffset <= 0 || verticalOffset <= 0)
                {
                    //reached top or bottom
                    return;
                }

                if (verticalOffset > previousVerticalOffset)
                {
                    //Scroll down
                    if (!popularHidden)
                    {
                        MainImageSlideOut.Begin();
                        popularHidden = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Scroll up
                    if (popularHidden)
                    {
                        MainImageSlideIn.Begin();
                        popularHidden = false;
                    }
                }
                previousVerticalOffset = verticalOffset;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `ScrollViewer` you're trying to handle the manipulation events, set the ManipulationMode to All - or as need.

Read more:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.manipulationmode